# How to use regex pattern in java?

Tags: java, regex

Hi i am new to regex i have to break a string according to my need

i hava a string s1;

```
S=1 Agra                  Achhnera                            NIL
  2 Agra                   Agra                               NIL
  3 Agra                   Fatehabad nagar                    NIL
  4 Agra                   Fatehpur Sikri                     NIL
  5 Aligarh                 Aligarh                           1300.00
  6 Siddharth Nagar         Naugarh                           NIL
  7 Siddharth Nagar         Sahiyapur                         NIL
  8 palam Nagar             Shohratgarh                       NIL;
```

i want to get this string like this

```
S=1 Agra                  Achhnera                            NIL
  2 Agra                   Agra                               NIL
  3 Agra                   Fatehabadnagar                     NIL
  4 Agra                   FatehpurSikri                      NIL
  5 Aligarh                 Aligarh                           1300.00
  6 SiddharthNagar         Naugarh                            NIL
  7 SiddharthNagar         Sahiyapur                          NIL
  8 palamNagar             Shohratgarh                        NIL
```

How can i achieve my desired output

Thanks in advance

Goted output

```
1 AgraAchhnera NIL
2 AgraAgra NIL
3 AgraFatehabad NIL
4 AgraFatehpur SikriNIL
```

Comment: Hope you have tried to solve it yourself.

Comment: please add the code you have tried so far

Comment: i tried  from my orignal string so i set String s  now i want to covert s as my desired output

Answer (score 1):

find `/([a-zA-Z]+)\s([a-zA-Z]+)/g`

and replace with `\1\2` or `$1$2` whichever backreference your language supports

demo here :

http://regex101.com/r/hN3uQ4

Comment: i am using like this but it is not  working in my code "  htmlTableText=htmlTableText.replace("/([a-zA-Z]+)\\s([a-zA-Z]+)/g","$1$2");"

Comment: in java, there is no need to use the begin and end character `/`. The same goes for the options. (`replaceAll` is the same as if you would use the `g` option). So it's `replaceAll("([a-zA-Z]+)\\s([a-zA-Z]+)", somestring);`

Comment: i used this but i am getting output like my posted output