# How to use regex in string in java?

Tags: java, regex

Hi i am having a string   which i want to break  using regex or a by any method

my string is

```
  1 Agra Achhnera NIL
  2 Agra Agra NIL
  3 Agra Fatehabad NIL
  4 Agra Fatehpur Sikri NIL
  5 Aligarh Aligarh 1300.00
  6 Aligarh Khair 1300.00
  7 Ambedkar Nagar Akbarpur NIL
  8 Ambedkar Nagar Tanda Akbarpur 1478.00
```

in result i want string like this:-

```
1 Agra Achhnera NIL
2 Agra Agra NIL
3 Agra Fatehabad NIL
4 Agra FatehpurSikri NIL
5 Aligarh Aligarh 1300.00
6 Aligarh Khair 1300.00
7 AmbedkarNagar Akbarpur NIL
18 AmbedkarNagar TandaAkbarpur 1478.00
```

How can i achieve this

my java code

```
<%@page import="com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.BrowserVersion;"%>
<%@page import="org.openqa.selenium.By;"%>
<%@page import="org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;"%>
<%@page import="org.openqa.selenium.WebElement"%>
<%@page import="org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver"%>
<%@page import="org.openqa.selenium.htmlunit.HtmlUnitDriver"%>
<%@page import="org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.Select"%>

<%


 WebDriver driver = new HtmlUnitDriver(BrowserVersion.getDefault());
        String sDate = "27/03/2014";

        String url="http://www.upmandiparishad.in/commodityWiseAll.aspx";
        driver.get(url);
        Thread.sleep(5000);

        new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ddl_commodity"))).selectByVisibleText("Jo");
         driver.findElement(By.id("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_txt_rate")).sendKeys(sDate);

        Thread.sleep(3000);
        driver.findElement(By.id("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_btn_show")).click();
        Thread.sleep(5000);


        WebElement findElement = driver.findElement(By.id("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_GridView1"));
        String htmlTableText = findElement.getText();
        // do whatever you want now, This is raw table values.
   htmlTableText=htmlTableText.replace("S.No.DistrictMarketPrice","");
  htmlTableText= htmlTableText.replaceAll("\\s(\\d+\\s[A-Z])", "<br>$1");
   //System.out.println(htmlTableText);
String data[]=htmlTableText.split("");
   out.println(data[9]);



        driver.close();
        driver.quit();
%>
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: lol omg this is the third question :D

Comment: is this text present in a file ?

Comment: @aelorif u will see this proper u will find diffrence

Comment: @aelor see this link what  output i ma getting http://regex101.com/r/qS2dJ6

Comment: i am sorry buddy but i really dont have any idea what rule you are following. in the 4th line you join the sencond and third word and in the 7th line you join the first and second

Comment: thats why dont say dear this same this is too much diffrent

Comment: okay tell me one thing: on what basis have you joined the first and second word in the 7th line ?

Comment: ambedkar nagar is a city  so i  joined

Comment: bhai ambedkarnagar is a city, only we know. A regex will not know which parses regular language. better search for another alternative

Comment: i think u r right brother actually i am  more confused

Comment: i scraped data from here  http://www.upmandiparishad.in/commodityWiseAll.aspx and want to insert in db thats id

Comment: then you need to change the format you scrap the data. only then regex will be helpful

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22831176/how-to-use-regex-pattern-in-java  duplicate

Comment: Why don't you post your Java code?

Comment: ok i am posting my whole java code

Comment: i posted my java code

Comment: ok now answer why `Agra Achhnera` not becoming `AgraAchhnera` like `AmbedkarNagar Akbarpur`. You need to define your rules of replacement properly.

Comment: u can see here why it is like this http://www.upmandiparishad.in/commodityWiseAll.aspx

Comment: commodity jo  date=  27/03/2014

Comment: @user3456343 listen according to your data scraping I can see that, places where there are `1 space` are one city and need to be joined. Other places we can let be

Comment: yes 1 space is one city

Answer (score 0):

this will work in your particular case beacause the data you are scraping is in this format and the below regex will work in most cases. I am not saying that this is the perfect answer but I should tell you that this will keep you going:

find

```
[a-z]\s[A-Z]
```

and replace with `\1\2`

demo here :
http://regex101.com/r/kF8vG6

Comment: how did u get   particular string which used in this regex

Comment: @user3456343 you mean this one : `[a-z]\s[A-Z]` ??

Comment: not this one  i am asking about string on which u tested this regex

Comment: @user3456343 i got it from the source you gave http://www.upmandiparishad.in/commodityWiseAll.aspx commodity paddy and date 31/03/2014