# How to break string using regex pattern in java?

Tags: java, regex

Hi i am having  astring which i want to break  as my desired string 
my orignal string is

```
s=1 Agra Achhnera NIL 2 Agra Agra NIL 3 Agra Fatehabad NIL 4 Agra Fatehpur Sikri NIL 5 Agra Jagner NIL 6 Agra Jarar NIL 7 Agra Khairagarh NIL 8 Agra Shamshabad NIL 9 Aligarh Atrauli NIL 10 Aligarh Chharra NIL 11 Aligarh Aligarh 1300.00 12 Aligarh Khair 1300.00 13 Allahabad Allahabad NIL 14 Allahabad Jasra NIL 15 Allahabad Leriyari NIL 16 Allahabad Sirsa NIL 17 Ambedkar Nagar Akbarpur NIL 18 Ambedkar Nagar Tanda Akbarpur NIL
```

my desired string is

```
1       Agra    Achhnera    NIL
2   Agra    Agra    NIL
3   Agra    Fatehabad   NIL
4   Agra    Fatehpur Sikri  NIL
5   Agra    Jagner  NIL
6   Agra    Jarar   NIL
7   Agra    Khairagarh  NIL
8   Agra    Shamshabad  NIL
9   Aligarh     Aligarh     NIL
10  Aligarh     Atrauli     NIL
11  Aligarh     Chharra     1300.00
12  Aligarh     Khair   1300.00
13  Allahabad   Allahabad   NIL
14  Allahabad   Jasra   NIL
15  Allahabad   Leriyari    NIL
16  Allahabad   Sirsa   NIL
17  Ambedkar Nagar  Akbarpur    NIL
18  Ambedkar Nagar  Tanda Akbarpur  NIL
```

How can i achieve my desired string   from my orignal string

Comment: Also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22831176/how-to-use-regex-pattern-in-java

Comment: it's even the same user...

Comment: Can do this all day...

Comment: @devnull  dear see proper and then comment its not duplicate

Comment: @user3456343 what have you tried?

Comment: i tried   htmlTableText= htmlTableText.replaceAll("\\s(\\d+\\s[A-Z])", "\n$1")

Answer (score 0):

If all you want to do is split the string after each occurrence of 'NIL' you can use the Java String.Split method.  You don't need a regex.

See if this helps: [How to split a string in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3481828/how-to-split-a-string-in-java)

Answer (score 0):

```
StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(youOriginalString, " ");
String theStringYouWant = "";
Integer i = 0;

while(st.hasMoreElements()) {
    theStringYouWant += st.next().toString();
    i++;
    if (i % 4 == 0) {
        theStringYouWant += "\n"; 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need regex  pattern for that simple string:

```
    String s= 1 Agra Achhnera NIL 2 Agra Agra NIL 3 Agra Fatehabad NIL 4 Agra Fatehpur Sikri NIL 5 Agra Jagner NIL 6 Agra Jarar NIL 7 Agra Khairagarh NIL 8 Agra Shamshabad NIL 9 Aligarh Atrauli NIL 10 Aligarh Chharra NIL 11 Aligarh Aligarh 1300.00 12 Aligarh Khair 1300.00 13 Allahabad Allahabad NIL 14 Allahabad Jasra NIL 15 Allahabad Leriyari NIL 16 Allahabad Sirsa NIL 17 Ambedkar Nagar Akbarpur NIL 18 Ambedkar Nagar Tanda Akbarpur NIL  
    String[] parts = string.split(" ");
    for(String string: parts){
        System.out.print(string); 
        if (string.equals("NIL"))
            System.out.print("\n");
        else 
            System.out.print("\t");
}
```

It's not so nice like using a regex pattern but you are gonna have less headaches.

Comment: in some  palace insted of nil digit are available

Comment: @user3456343 I can not see this condition in your question !!!

Comment: condition is that aftel nil  or iplace of nill whatever is availlable i have to break string in new line

Comment: i updated my desired output